# Create alias for npm run

Tags: node.js

Just a trivial, but possibly useful question.
I have the following npm script:

```
"start:iso:dev:win": "npm run clean:build:win && set NODE_ENV=development&& concurrently \"npm run build:client:dev\" \"wait-on public\\build\\index-dev.html && npm run build:server:dev\"",
```

Since multi-lining doesn't seem to be possible does NodeJS offer a shorthand syntax for npm run to make the line just a bit briefer?
Alternatively, is there an easy (transparent) way to create an alias?

The result would be something like:

```
"start:iso:dev:win": "run clean:build:win && set NODE_ENV=development&& concurrently \"run build:client:dev\" \"wait-on public\\build\\index-dev.html && run build:server:dev\"",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. How you're doing it is the recommended way by npm, even if it makes no sense. But then again, a lot of what npm does makes no sense.

[Here's a Github issue asking for the feature](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6943), which was expressly declined without any good reason or discussion from the community - as is to be expected from npm.

This has been a pain point for years, and I don't think anything will be done about it because it's tangled up in mindless politics and a company that doesn't care about its users.

The only other alternative is to automate whatever it is you're doing via a platform-independent scripting language - the usual case being Node.js - in lieu of shell scripts.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: I checked out the shell script solution, but it appears to complicate things further, which I'm not really in favor of. It's sort of trivial so I can live with it.

Comment: As a maintainer of two of the top-10 packages on npm, I can say with full confidence that `something better would be more complicated; I can live with what's there` is pretty much the sad reality of node.js. I wish you luck :)

Comment: I don't disagree with you, but it depends on the complexity. What I have is a line of commands that is still readable. If it were to go out of hand, I will write a script for it :-) But I do agree that more internal convenience could be offered for writing npm scripts. Alternatively a string builder as isolated package could help for convenience, but haven't heared about this yet.

Comment: I know, I was agreeing with you - the entire Node.js ecosystem is crufty and bulky where it doesn't need to be. There should be a simple solution here but due to an army of political developers and non-stop bikeshedding and fragility, nothing ever gets improved.